# intel xdk google play games services

Tags: cordova, google-play-games, intel-xdk

Is it possible to access the native Google Play Games Services through **Intel XDK** ?
will I have to use the Web version or android version?
is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The Intel XDK produces standard Cordova (aka PhoneGap) apps. Thus, the techniques you use to access native features in the XDK are identical to those you use with a Cordova app (since it *is* a Cordova app). That means you need to use Cordova plugins to access native features of the target device.

Thus, search SO and other resources using your favorite search engine for "cordova phonegap google play game services" or similar...